# Where Can I Find the Throttling Temperature and Shutdown Temperature for a CPU?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking, throttling, temperature

I am going to do some improvements to a Multi-Threaded program that I wrote,
and after each improvement I would like to measure the results, by running the program for some time.

Those tests will be CPU intensive,
and since I compare each experiment with the one before it,
I need the comparison to be unaffected by CPU Throttling.

For this reason, I would like to find some kind of information about my CPU,
that shows Temperature Ranges, and their effect on the CPU's speed.

For example, something like this:
**0-60°C**: No Throttling
**60-70°C**: Throttling -20% Clock Speed
**70-80°C**: Throttling -50% Clock Speed
**80°C and Above**: CPU Shutdown

(this is fake info that I just wrote, to explain the idea,
it's not the real info about my CPU)

My CPU is `Intel i3-3220`,
but my question is not just about this specific CPU, but generally abouts CPUs..
(both Intel and AMD).

Intel's product page for this CPU model does not mention any info about Throttling Temperatures..
https://ark.intel.com/products/65693/Intel-Core-i3-3220-Processor-3M-Cache-3_30-GHz

Where can I find this information, when having a CPU model?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For other Intel CPUs, this information can generally be found under the header `Thermal Margin Slope` near the end of the `Thermal Management` section in the Datasheet, Vol. 1. For instance, for 8th Gen Core CPUs, see [8th Gen Core Family Datasheet, Vol. 1](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/8th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html).

[Here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-technical-resources.html) you can find links to the datasheets for other generations of Intel processors.

See also [this guide](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-1800828/intel-temperature-guide.html) for general information about CPU temperatures, which will help in deciphering Intel's less-than-consistent datasheet language. The guide also lists many common processors and their throttling temperatures, these should be the same for other CPUs with the same PCG designation.

Unfortunately, for whatever reason, Intel has omitted all Thermal Management information in [the datasheet for the specific CPU you mentioned](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/processors/core/3rd-gen-core-desktop-vol-1-datasheet.html) (it also for some reason redirects you elsewhere if you try to access the datasheet on intel.com, therefore the link goes to intel.co.uk, where it works fine), and I was unable to find the document they refer to instead, namely the `Desktop 3rd Generation Intel Core Processor Family, Desktop Intel Pentium Processor, Desktop Intel Celeron Processor, and LGA1155 Socket Thermal and Mechanical Specifications and Design Guidelines.`. Quite the mouthful, in addition to being hard to find.

Since you mentioned an interest in this information about CPUs in general, I hope I could be of some help nonetheless.

Comment: In some cases, such as the 3rd Gen i7 CPUs, Intel calibrated the throttling temperatures on a part-by-part basis. Therefore, the information is not available for these CPUs.